# How can I convert a large number of Word documents to HTML as fast as possible?

Tags: windows-xp, conversion, microsoft-office-2007, html

I have to convert 500 Microsoft Word 2003 files into HTML documents. What would be the shortest possible way?

I'm not just talking about extension .doc to HTML. I want to convert word files's data into HTML tags.

Word 2007 is installed in my system.

Any suggestion which can help to accomplish this task quickly would be nice.

If you will suggest any tool then that should not be commercial. Should be free or portable.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [this](http://www.convertwordtohtml.com/) with some pretty good results.

Comment: it's commercial

Comment: @Jitendra vyas - if you're looking for a free solution you should clarify this in your question.

Comment: IIRC, the free trial is not crippled in any way, it just stops working after a set interval (I think it was 7 days). If this conversion is a one-time thing, then that should be plenty of time to do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Google Docs will do it for you :)

Just go to docs.google.com, log in, upload your word file, the go File->Download as->HTML(zipped), and you'll be able to download your word doc in html form inside a zip file.

I'm sure you could automate this with a script somehow, there's an api available.  See http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocs

Answer (score 2):

@MrStatic's solution looks good, I was not aware of any program capable of doing it.

If that doesn't work for you, I would advise that you download a macro program such as [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and simply record a macro to do everything then close the current document, alt tab to the open folder and move down to the next document (use details view) and repeat.

Comment: I voted it up because I didn't see the question has been answered.

Comment: @Wil but all document will have different content

Comment: That is irrelevant, you will be doing the same task - open up, file/orb > save as/export, html > save... so, you can create a macro/script that does this on a loop to get through all files.

Comment: Yes you can. So in reality you only have to do this once Just read over this section. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to automate it with VBScript - create a filesystemobject, enumerate a folder with your source files in, open them one by one in Word, and Save As in a suitable HTML format.

Google said [this](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/exporting-word-files-to-html/).  It's written for Word 2003, but if word 2007 has matching interfaces for compatibility reasons, you might be in luck, and it might work without modification.  If not, I'd hope changes would be small, Word 2007 should still support a SaveAs function of some sort.  Shame on MS if they changed it since Word 2003...

Comment: I successfully used this script with Word 2013, so it should be compatible with everything in between.

Answer (score 1):

WordWebNav (WWN) can batch-convert Word-docs to Word-HTML (filtered).

WWN is free and open-source. (In full disclosure, I'm the author.)
https://jimyuill.com/software/www/WordWebNav/

Word-HTML has limitations and bugs. For example, paragraphs are as wide as the browser, so they are often unreadable.
WWN creates usable Word web-pages, and it fixes Word-HTML bugs.

WWN's batch-conversion tool is a Word macro (VBA), in generate_word_html.docm
https://github.com/jimyuill/word-web-nav/tree/main/tools